# android - what is this notification function call in android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to build a notification that receive a message from the server, database or other terminal?
I want it can be like the instant messenger apps that is not opening, but it can received message and show a notification.

I want to know what is this call and what element i need?

Comment: Hi @roy0287 and welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow doesn't tend to work well when you ask an open ended question like the above (as those discussions tend to end up degenerating into flame wars - I'm sure you've seen the carnage left in old forums).

What might work better is if produce a minimal working example of what you'd like to do, and then go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [push notifications](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Push-Notification-Android/)

Comment: thank you, i search for it and i think it is absolutely what i want

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.